# Is there a way to group by one minute periods in MySQL using unix timestamps?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a MariaDB database holding some data for a game and I wanted to use Grafana to graph out how many rows have been inserted every minute. I'm using a Node.js script to fetch the data every minute from the game's Public API and insert it into my db, however I can't figure out how to get MySQL to output something that works with Grafana. What I need it to do is output a table with a column for the number of new inserts and the time at the start of the one minute window. My DB looks something like this:

```
 --------------------------------------------------------------------
| auction_id | seller | buyer | timestamp | price | bin | item_bytes |
 --------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have a working query for returning the number of new inserts for the current data supplied by the API, however I can't figure out how to get the historical data for the past minutes. The output I'm looking for would look something like this:

```
 -----------------------------
| new inserts |   timestamp   |
 -----------------------------
|     234     | 1625373706053 |
 -----------------------------
|     684     | 1625373666053 |
 -----------------------------
|     720     | 1625373626053 |
 -----------------------------
|     403     | 1625373586053 |
 -----------------------------
```

Notice how the timestamp goes down by `60,000` every row, which is equivalent to 60 seconds, or a minute. I have tried using GROUP BY and almost every other solution I could find on StackOverflow and other sites, however it still doesn't work.

Please don't hesitate to comment if I wasn't clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` to convert your milliseconds-since-epoch values into a bona fide datetime.  Then, aggregate by minute to get the counts:

```sql
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS `new inserts`,
    FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp / 1000, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') AS ts_minute
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY ts_minute
ORDER BY ts_minute;
```

Comment: note that this aggregates on even minutes, not 46.053 seconds after the minute as the example seems to show